# tar: --exclude=".git": Cannot stat: No such file or directory

Tags: macos, tar

This is driving me crazy. I want to `tar` a directory, but exclude some files. This is my command:

```
tar -zcvf $NAME-$VERSION.tar.gz $NAME-$VERSION --exclude='.git' --exclude='.gitignore'
```

While the above command works on RedHat EL5, it doesn't work on Mac OS 10.8.2. I have tried replacing the `'` with `"`, `\'` and `\"`. I have tried removing the equal signs. Nothing works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `gnutar` from Brew, MacPort, etc. Apple's tar is too crippled.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

All the options need to be together before the arguments, and the `-f` flag needs to precede the tar file:

```
tar -zcv \
  --exclude='.git' \
  --exclude='.gitignore' \
  -f $NAME-$VERSION.tar.gz \
  $NAME-$VERSION
```

Comment: If you do `tar --help`, does the `--exclude` option appear in the help?  I don't know OSX but perhaps there's a `gtar` instead of the stock `tar`.

Comment: Ah I see it :) try this:

`tar --exclude='.git' --exclude='.gitignore' -zcvf $NAME-$VERSION.tar.gz $NAME-$VERSION`

The `-f` flag expects a filename as the next argument.

Comment: Sorry yes, edited.  I'm new here so bear with me!

Comment: Can attest that this works on a Mac - 10.9.  Took me a while to find the right version of this which is why I leave my comment here!

Answer (score 2):

This gives you what you want:

```
tar czvf \
  $NAME-$VERSION.tar.gz \
  $NAME-$VERSION \
  --wildcards \
  --exclude=.git \
  --exclude=.gitignore
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to filter .git meta directories. The easiest way is using `--exclude-vcs` to exclude Version Control System (VCS) directories:

```
tar -zcvf $NAME-$VERSION.tar.gz $NAME-$VERSION --exclude-vcs
```

I have used "tar (GNU tar) 1.27.1" on my Linux machine, it seems mac's BSD General Command(non GNU version) does not support this option.

Comment: Are you certain this works with Apple's tar? See Apple's [`tar(1)` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tar.1.html). it does not list `--exclude-vsc` or `--exclude-vcs`.

Comment: Thanks dear @jww for your hint. I have edited my answer to be more effective.